# QtWebKit support

Tags: html, qt4, qwebkit

I'm building an embedded program to mini6410, the responsible provided me with qt 4.7 ready to be used to the cross-compilation. I tried to use more recent version of qt without success, so i'm stuck with webkit 2.0

The problem is that I couldn't play video and/or audio that uses html5, i researched and found that version 2.0 doesn't have "full" support to it.

How can i solve this problem? I mean, can I configure another version of webkit to my qt or can I configure "manually" a plugin that supports html5?

Comment: Qt 4.7 is totally outdated, and even the LTS version 4.8 is quite dated, though I'm just now not sure if it's already at EOL. For new projects, and if you depend on fast-moving, security-relevant features like web support, I strongly recommend using a current Qt 5.

Comment: Yeah, i really do appreciate, bro. I'm gonna keep trying to make this cross compilation work otherwise we'll be in qt 6 and i'm not gonne be able to be free of 4.7
Ty once again!